# Same XPath for two elements on two different pages. How to access them using Selenium WebDriver in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to verify page header titles on two different pages.

1. Accessing the site and verifying the page header title.
2. Entering an input in text field and clicking on submit button.
3. Verifying the page header title

Page from step 1 and step 3 has same `xpath` for header titles, when I'm trying to access and verify, I get an error message:

> expected(expected title) but found(unexpected title)

Code:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/h1/span
/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/h1/span
```

Screenshots for HTML Code :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide HTMLcode?

Comment: what do you mean by page header title? Are you pointing Window(browser tab) title?

Comment: Sorry how do i add screenshots here. I cannot see any attachment options. Im new stackoverflow.

Comment: @santhoshkumar I meant to say , Page header inside <h1> tag which is present on top of the page.

Comment: when you do syso both page titles, what the thing printed in console? Is both are same?\

Comment: @santhoshkumar I have added HTML code screenshots.

Comment: You have mentioned, when I'm trying to access and verify, I got an error message... What are you trying to verify?.. I have seen the screenshots and both are having different texts

Comment: @santhoshkumar When I navigate on a page after clicking on submit button, I have to verify that I'm on the correct page by verifying using header title on the page. If you see my screenshots and if you can observe the text , they are different. One title says 'Compare gas & electricity' and anotther title says 'Start your search' . But its xpath is same. So now I have to get text 'Start your search' and assert it. Long story short. I need to get 'Star your search' text using xpath. How can I get it. I hope I am clear. sorry for confusion

Comment: Can you give us the code that you have tried?

Comment: @santhoshkumar 'code' WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20) 
 WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/h1/span"));  String header_title=element.getText();   Assert.assertEquals(header_title,"START YOUR SEAR");   System.out.println("Successfully landed on Step 1 page");

Comment: what does System.out.println(header_title); prints. Is it "START YOUR SEAR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a timing issue, the driver still reading the old header. You can use [Expected Conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to wait for the text to become what you are waiting for

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement header = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/h1/span"), "expected title"));
```

Or wait for the first header to become stale

```
WebElement firstHeader = driver.findElement(...);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(firstHeader));
WebElement secondHeader = driver.findElement(...);
```

> Edit

If its the same element you can use `textToBePresentInElement`

```
WebElement header = driver.findElement(...);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(header, "expected title"));
```

Comment: I tried your second option. It gives timeout error. Expected condition failed:waiting for element to become stale and timed out.

Comment: @Parveen I add another option.

Comment: 'WebElement header = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='goCompare']/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/h1/span"));
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(header, "START YOUR SEARCH"));
 String header1=header.getText();
 Assert.assertEquals(header1, "START YOUR SEARCH");
 System.out.println("Succesfully on step 1 page");'

Comment: Thanks . I got it solved by using above code. Let me know if its right or not a good practice